# How to reset windows and Chrome settings when user finishes using computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome

At the school I work for we have a small computer lab, recently we have been having some problems with users who install chrome extensions, change chrome settings and install programs on the computer.

We'd like to have some kind of program that protect both windows and chrome settings.

Something like when closing the session or rebooting the computer all the changes the user could do were reverted to the original state.

It will be nice to have all the user downloads deleted as well.

Also, we might need some way to block some pages that are not allowed to access such as adult pages.

A quick search landed me with Faronics Deep Freeze which according to the salesperson is subscription-based I don't think managers will approve this software. Do you know of any other software with the same features? Free open source software is also welcome.

Comment: You can image the disks, let students do what they need (or want) to do, and than restore either the whole disk or just areas that are frequently changed. Or put the whole OS on DVD - easy to do with Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How can I do that? which software do I need?

Comment: Any disk imaging software, e.g. Macrium Reflect Free, https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree , on one of the numerous alternatives. You are stating you **don't** regularly make disk image backups??

Comment: No, we don't have image backups. Thanks for the recommendation. I'll check this type of software